# How can I use Windows cmd to find a folder path using where?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-line

I use Windows 10. There is a "Microsoft VS Code" folder in "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code" and I want to find it using [`where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where) in cmd.

Now, I am not 100% sure about the folder name, so I want to search for "[maybe something preceding here]VS Code", "VS Code", or "VSCode", all case-insensitive.

In regular expression, that should be `/VS\s?Code$/i` as in `preg_match("/VS\s?Code$/i", "Microsoft VS Code")`.

How can I write that simple pattern in `where /R C:\ <pattern>`?
I cannot use "" or '' in pattern to bracket "VS Code" and whitespace is taken to mean **or**. Would `VS.?Code` work to say an optional space?

So my questions are:

- `where` only finds file paths, how can I make it to find also folder paths?
- how to write the search pattern?

Comment: Or, you can use `-Filter` provided by the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet in PowerShell: `Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\path" -Filter "*vs*code*" -Directory -Recurse`.

Comment: you say you wan to use `where` in cmd ... that would be `where.exe`. so ... what does this have to do with powershell?

Comment: `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ChildItem -Filter *VS?Code -Directory` returns nothing and `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\path" -Filter "*vs*code*" -Directory -Recurse` returns access to path xxx is denied

Comment: Did you type your actual path in, and not "c:\path"? Lol otherwise, try `-Force`. Sounds like a permissions issue if that doesn't help either; recommend making sure you're running as admin.

Comment: `where.exe` is used to find an executable file in `%PATH%`, not a tool to find files

Answer (score 0):

`where` is an exe, not a PowerShell command

in powershell use the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\" -Filter "*vs*code*" -Directory -Recurse
```

you will get some error message (due to permissions problem), you can fix them by changing `c:\` to the path you want.

Comment: In Windows, _(as specifically mentioned in the question title, and versioned in the question body)_, `where.exe` is a built-in executable utiliy. As a Command Line Interface utility, it will work within the Command Prompt, or PowerShell Prompt. It may not be a PowerShell built-in cmdlet, _(more accurate)_, but there is no technical reason why it cannot be run in a Windows PowerShell session.

Comment: and `where.exe` is an equivalent to `Get-Command`, not `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` which is the equivalent to `dir /s`

Comment: Actually, `where` is an alias in PowerShell for `Where-Object`. The `where.exe` command can be used in PowerShell, but the `.exe` must be specified. Better yet, specify `%__APPDIR__%where.exe`.